# Download speed decreasing slowly before stop

Tags: wget, download-speed

I think it's a problem with my distro. Each download (wget, chrome or anything except uGet) slowly decreases its speed. I don't know what to do, I needed to install a snap package and it stops at around 50%.

Also, I don't think it's my network, because everything works fine on Windows and on my Android device with Termux.

I don't know what's going on, but I am ready to provide additional information.

Comment: Transmission downloads are with same issue too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a half of day of research, i discovered that WLAN power managment is on.

### First of all, i checked the device name:

```bsh
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"INTERNET_O_SUL_ADRIANA_5G "  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=30 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:27   Missed beacon:0

lxcbr0    no wireless extensions.

anbox0    no wireless extensions.

veth5TGA4C  no wireless extensions.
```

As you can see, my device is `wlo1`.

### Then I turned off Power Managment by doing:

```bsh
sudo iwconfig wlo1 power off
```

### Finally, i applied the changes for the next reboot:

```bsh
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

On this file, i just changed:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

by:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Well, i hope no one more gets this issue. Also, i dont know why this setting is activated on my Ubuntu, probably its the default setting.